# Error in rails console when interacting with database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been getting this persistent error every time I try to update my table in rails.

For example if my code in the schema.rb file is:

```
  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

If I go into the rails console and write the command:

```
book = Book.new(title: "a book", description: "a book description")
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Errno::EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/input-method.rb:42:in `winsize'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/input-method.rb:42:in `winsize'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:753:in `output_value'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:545:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:704:in `signal_status'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:538:in `block in eval_input'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:166:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:151:in `loop'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:151:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:150:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:150:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:537:in `eval_input'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:472:in `block in run'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:471:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:471:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:400:in `start'
Maybe IRB bug!
```

I can continue and write `book.save` which will update the new book into the database however I not sure if this error message is a concern. It wasn't there previously when running this command and is now there on all projects when trying to update any tables.

I've completely reinstalled Ruby 2.7 and RubyMine and this error still returns. I'm not sure what this problem is caused by.

Thank you for any advice.

(Info: working on Windows machine on RubyMine. Using rails 5.2.4 and Ruby 2.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a known problem with IRB and Ruby 2.7 so could you please add your vote there:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-26249